# npm install EACCES error on windows

Tags: node.js, npm

I've tried to run cmd as administrator, to change permissions on nodejs folder in Program Files, to login as Administrator, to runas /norprofile..., even to run command in safe mode. Always the same error when I run "npm install uglify-js".

```
C:\Users\user123>npm install uglify-js
npm ERR! Error: connect EACCES
npm ERR!     at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
npm ERR!     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)
npm ERR!  { [Error: connect EACCES] code: 'EACCES', errno: 'EACCES', syscall: 'connect' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "uglify-js"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\user123
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno EACCES
npm ERR! stack Error: connect EACCES
npm ERR! stack     at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
npm ERR! stack     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user123\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

C:\Users\user123>
```

Anybody have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Do you have any firewalls or other security software running on the system that may be blocking the outbound connection? Do you require an http/https proxy to access the internet?

Comment: I don't have any firewalls and my internet connection has direct access to the internet.

Comment: The problem was with windows firewall which I was not aware it was turned on. Now I turned it off, and without any problems, npm installed desired package. Sorry for false alarm.

Answer (score 13):

After turn off the **kaspersky**, it can connect the server to download **node modules**

Answer (score 4):

As noted above:

> The problem was with windows firewall which I was not aware it was turned on. Now I turned it off, and without any problems, npm installed desired package.

**References**

- [npm wiki: Troubleshooting](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting)
- [Microsoft C Runtime Library Reference: ErrNo Constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5814770t.aspx)
- [Microsoft C Runtime Library Reference: Global Variables - errno, _doserrno, _sys, errlist, and_sys_errlist](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3ayayh1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I get a similar error but for a Nodejs program that continuously connects to MongoLab (not just installing or updating a module)... so I added a Windows firewall exception specifically for Nodejs, and the host and port my program is connecting to.