# Error Install Bower

Tags: bower

I'm Wira and I'm a newbie
So recently i tried to install bower on my laptop and there are some errors like this:

```
C:\Users\wiraxie>npm install g- bower
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodej
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "g-" "bower"
npm ERR! node v4.4.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno EACCES
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! Error: connect EACCES 151.101.76.162:443
npm ERR!     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:873:11)
npm ERR!     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:896:20)
npm ERR!     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1077:14)
npm ERR!  { [Error: connect EACCES 151.101.76.162:443]
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   errno: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'connect',
npm ERR!   address: '151.101.76.162',
npm ERR!   port: 443 }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\wiraxie\npm-debug.log
```

Can Anyone help me?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install bower with

```
npm install -g bower
```

and make sure your **[run the Command Prompt as an Administrator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813(v=ws.10).aspx)**

Comment: Try these answers.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26192865/npm-install-eacces-error-on-windows