# npm install cordova cmd admin

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

I just dont know what am I doing wrong here .
I am running cmd in elevated aministrator mode
My directory C:\nxp> has full permissions. 
but when ever i execute npm install -g cordova.
I even try npm install -g cordova -f after clearing cache but still no luck

Is there away i can just download cordova without npm on windows...

```
C:\nxp>npm install -g cordova
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\nxp\\node.exe" "C:\\nxp\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js"
"install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v4.4.3
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno EACCES
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! Error: connect EACCES 151.101.80.162:443
npm ERR!     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
npm ERR!     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
npm ERR!     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1061:14)
npm ERR!  { [Error: connect EACCES 151.101.80.162:443]
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   errno: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'connect',
npm ERR!   address: '151.101.80.162',
npm ERR!   port: 443 }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\nxp\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you try running the command prompt as admin and doing `npm i -g cordova` ?

Comment: It looks like it is failing to connect to the IP address `151.101.80.162` which wouldn't have much to do with your computer. Their server may just be down.

Comment: @CodingWithSpike The error is EACCES which means permission denied. It seems as if there is some firewall in between blocking the connection. OP should try to disable the firewall and try or add an exception for npm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm install EACCES error on windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26192865/npm-install-eacces-error-on-windows)

Comment: Hi Thanks guys  executing this command actually   npm i -g cordova   
After it tried install showed that it couldn't  connect due to firewall  .

I whitelisted in firewall and than it now works .