# Cannot Update NPM

Tags: npm

**So, I've Got This Error When I Tried To Update NPM To The Lastest Version.**
I Used This Command To Update NPM:

```
npm install -g npm@lastest
```

````
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/abbrev'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/abbrev'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/abbrev'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2021-07-21T03_44_06_161Z-debug.log```
````

Comment: Welcome to SO! Did you try it with `sudo` ("try running the command again as root/Administrator"), `sudo npm install -g npm@lastest`? Or use an elevated Powershell or whatever Windows does (I use [gsudo](https://github.com/gerardog/gsudo))? What's your OS?

Comment: no... i've never tried that before. i am going to try it

Comment: My OS is windows

Comment: no its not working it says: bash: sudo command not found

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm install EACCES error on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26192865/npm-install-eacces-error-on-windows)

Comment: on windows, there is no sudo kind of thing you need to run your cmd as administrator.

Comment: If you're using Windows you should run the command as administrator. Open the terminal or the app you're running the command on as administrator.

Comment: i used a website to code. it's called: https://replit.com

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because of permission issues.
If you're on windows open your cmd by right-clicking and selecting `Run as Administrator` then try to do an update or if you're on Mac use `sudo` before the command.